# c# how to get virtual IP assigned to terminal session in Windows 2008R2

Tags: c#, networking

I have Windows 2008 R2 server with enabled IP virtualization for Terminal services. I need to know in my program which virtual IP was assigned to session where I run my program.

Now when I get IP address:

```
        String strHostName = Dns.GetHostName();
       IPHostEntry ipEntry = Dns.GetHostByName(strHostName);
        IPAddress[] addr = ipEntry.AddressList;
```

I have only IP of a server not virtual IP assigned to session.

How can I get (using c#) this virtual IP?

Best regards,
Piotr

Comment: Have you checked this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13725966/674700)?

Answer (score 0):

you may try this

```
System.Net.IPAddress[] IpAddresses = System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(System.Net.Dns.GetHostName());

for (int i = 0; i < IpAddresses.Length; i++)
{
   Console.WriteLine("IP Address {0}: {1} ", i, IpAddresses[i].ToString());
}
```

Comment: no, it's not working. it returns IP of a server not virtual IP of session

Answer (score -1):

Use `WTSQuerySessionInformation`