# VB.net - Display Used Network Adapter?

Tags: vb.net

So I made a little programm which displays Ips, Macs and that stuff from all adapters the user has.

I searched up google but I didn't find anything on how to get the selected Adapter so I can tell the user that he is using this adapter currently.

Is there any function or class for this?

Comment: I did a Google search and it yielded roughly a few hundred thousand results, there are many ways to do this. Also this may be of help [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172962/how-to-determine-which-network-adapter-is-connected-to-the-internet)

Comment: Nvm I found a way ;)